# SQL Joining mutiple tables with repeated entries and count() group by

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query to join multiple tables together with count and group by but failed. (Beginner level)

There are two tables.
[two tables(t1, t2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lgdR.png)

the query result expected:
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0n3tI.png)

I can successfully do them separately but not joining them into one table.
Query 1:

```
select name, count(name) from t1
group by name;
```

Query 2:

```
select name, count(name) from t2
group by name;
```

Query 3:

```
select name, count(total.name) as totalNum
from (select name from t1 union all select name from t2) as total
group by name;
```

Query 4(failed):

```
select total.name, (select count(name) from t1) as t1count, (select count(name) from t2) as t2count
from (select name from t1 union select name from t2) as total
group by total.name;
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  They're not the same thing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally there should be some master table which contains all names you want to appear in your report.  For the purpose of illustration, we may use a CTE/subquery for this.  We can join this subquery to subqueries which take separate tallies in the two tables.

```
SELECT
    n.Name,
    COALESCE(t1.t1count, 0) AS t1count,
    COALESCE(t2.t2count, 0) AS t2count,
    COALESCE(t1.t1count, 0) + COALESCE(t2.t2count, 0) AS totalNum
FROM
(
    SELECT 'n1' AS Name UNION ALL
    SELECT 'n2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'n3' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'n4' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'n5'
) n
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Name, COUNT(*) AS t1count
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY Name
) t1
    ON n.Name = t1.Name
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Name, COUNT(*) AS t2count
    FROM t2
    GROUP BY Name
) t2
    ON n.Name = t2.Name;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that you *could* try to use a full outer join approach (even in MySQL), but that would only meet your requirements if both tables collectively contained all the names you wanted to appear.  If not, then it wouldn't work.

Comment: I have never seen the top bit syntaxes before. What would be the case say if there is a master table that has n1 to n5 listed as one of the columns specified as Name as well?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  This is precisely what my answer already assumes.

Comment: I don't understand COALESCE(t1.t1count, 0) AS t1count.  The w3schools didn't provide much info either.

Comment: `COALESCE(column, 0)` would return the `column` value, unless it is `NULL`, in which case it would return 0.  This, just as an example.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Just asking, is there a way to achieve it without using COALESCE()? If not, maybe just to retrieve Name, T1count, T2count, not totalNum without using COALESCE()?

Comment: You don't _need_ to use `COALESCE`, but if you remove it, then for names which have no actual data you would see `NULL` for the count instead of zero.  Up to you whether you want that behavior or not.

Comment: Oh, now I got it. Just tried it, Cheers. Perfect for learning purposes.